# don't working buttons with deploing for android

Tags: react-native, expo

assembled a mobile application on react-native under android / when you first start it appears a problem. Two buttons do not work. upon re-entry, they start working

```
blockUser = async () => {
  try {
    const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');
    await axios.post(`${SERVER}/api/v1/users/${this.state.userId}/block`, {
      headers: {
        'Access-token': ACCESS_TOKEN,
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
    this.setState({isBlocked: true, sayHi: this.state.sayHi === 0 ? 0 : 2});
    this.showToast(`You\'ve blocked ${this.state.name}`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error)
  }
};
likePhoto = (id) => {
  SecureStore.getItemAsync('token')
    .then((token) => axios.post(`${SERVER}/api/v1/images/${id}/like`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Access-token': ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    }))
    .then(() => this._genImages())
    .catch((e) => console.warn(e))
};
<TouchableOpacity
  key={index}
  style={[
    styles.reportBlockReason,
    selectReason === item.id ? {backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'} : {}
  ]}
  onPress={() => this.setState({selectReason: item.id})}
>
  <Text style={styles.reportBlockReasonText}>{item.title}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity
  key={index}
  style={[
    styles.reportBlockReason,
    selectReason === item.id ? {backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'} : {}
  ]}
  onPress={() => this.setState({selectReason: item.id})}
>
  <Text style={styles.reportBlockReasonText}>{item.title}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

There were no errors therefore I cannot determine the causes of this problem, nevertheless it must be solved